# Spark: Python Windowed Functions for Data Frames

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

The use case is to capture the difference in time between streaming sensor entries where the station and part are the same to compare against tolerances and potentially trigger an alert if it falls out of range. I'm currently parsing the fields into a data frame and registering it as a table to perform a SQL query using the LAG function.

```
events = rawFilter.map(lambda x: x.split("|")).map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2]))
eventSchema = StructType(
  [StructField("station", StringType(), False),
  StructField("part", StringType(), False),
  StructField("event", TimestampType(), False)])

eventDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(events,eventSchema)
eventDF.registerTempTable("events_table")

%sql select station, part, event, prev_event, 
    cast(event as double) - cast(prev_event as double) as CycleTime 
    from (select station, part, event, 
    LAG(event) over (Partition BY station, part Order BY event) as Prev_Event 
    from events_table) x limit 10

Example Streaming Sensor Data:
station1|part1|<timestamp>
station2|part2|<timestamp>
station3|part3|<timestamp>
station1|part1|<timestamp>
station1|part1|<timestamp>
station1|part1|<timestamp>
station3|part3|<timestamp>
station1|part1|<timestamp>
```

What I'm trying to understand is how would I accomplish the window function in the data frame so the resulting table would already compute the time difference?

Part 2 of this question is to understand how to handle when the part changes. In that case CycleTime should not be calculated or stop; however, the difference in time between the two different parts for the same Station is another calculation called ChangeOver. I don't see how this could be done with Spark Streaming because the window could extend over days before the Part changes. So I was thinking of pushing the data into Hbase or something else to calculate ChangeOver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window definitions on `DataFrames` closely follow SQL conventions with `partitionBy`, `orderBy`, `rangeBetween` and `rowsBetween` methods corresponding to the equivalent SQL clauses.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lag, unix_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

rawDF = sc.parallelize([
    ("station1", "part1", "2015-01-03 00:11:02"),
    ("station2", "part2", "2015-02-00 10:20:10"),
    ("station3", "part3", "2015-03-02 00:30:00"),
    ("station1", "part1", "2015-05-00 01:07:00"),
    ("station1", "part1", "2015-01-13 05:16:10"),
    ("station1", "part1", "2015-11-20 10:22:40"),
    ("station3", "part3", "2015-09-04 03:15:22"),
    ("station1", "part1", "2015-03-05 00:41:33")
]).toDF(["station", "part", "event"])

eventDF = rawDF.withColumn("event", unix_timestamp(col("event")))

w = Window.partitionBy(col("station")).orderBy(col("event"))

(eventDF
  .withColumn("prev_event", lag(col("event")).over(w))
  .withColumn("cycle_time", col("event") - col("prev_event")))
```

Comment: You nailed it!! I made the change you mentioned and had to add a cast to both dates. I also added the Part column to the PartitionBy function and resulted with the following...

`w = Window.partitionBy(col("Station"), col("Part")).orderBy(col("Event"))

resultDF = (eventDF
    .withColumn("Prev_Event", lag(col("Event")).over(w))
    .withColumn("Cycle_Time", col("Event").cast("double") - col("Prev_Event").cast("double")))`